# Codeigniter 3 - PHP 8 - Mail Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Since the update from PHP 7.4 to 8.1 I get strange messages by sending emails.

```
$config = Array(
             'protocol' => 'asmtp',
             'smtp_host' => 'asmtp.mail.*****.com',
             'smtp_port' => 587,
             'smtp_user' => 'mail@example.ch',
             'smtp_pass' => '*******',
             'mailtype' => 'html',
             'charset' => 'utf-8',
             'wordwrap' => TRUE
         ); 

        $message = $this->load->view('email/index.php', $data, TRUE);
        
        $subject = "My title;
        
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );
        $this->email->from('mail@example.ch');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach($root.'assets/'.$attachment);
```

Error message:

> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
> may not support this format.
>
> --B_ATC_64eceaf56642a Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_64eceaf566426"
>
> --B_ALT_64eceaf566426 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

---

> --B_ALT_64eceaf566426 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

I changed the charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 and some others but this doesn't solve the problem. Additionally, there was no change on the mailserver.

Comment: Those aren't "error messages", that is basically what the code of a multipart email looks like. If you get it shown as code, instead of properly interpreted, then something about the syntax must be off - a likely candidate are the line breaks. Try and remove `$this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );`, or make that just set `\n` explicitly.

Comment: I removed $this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" ); but still the same issue.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you go and check the actual source code of the received email. And compare that to a "proper" one, that was still displaying as expected.

Comment: None is shown correctly. That is my problem. I tried many things and the issue appears when I use 'mailtype' => 'html'

Comment: Still worth having a look at the source code at least, maybe there's something in there that immediately pops out as "wrong".

Comment: The chance is high that the issue has appeared since moving from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.